# Saturn Vue problems shifting

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, saturn, transmission-fluid

I have a 2004 Saturn Vue (Manual) and am having trouble shifting. When the car first starts, shifting feels gritty, almost like you are running your fingers down the teeth of a comb. After I have been driving for a minute, It loosens up and feels normal. Does anyone known what might be causing this? Results I have found are inconsistent. I am hoping it is something that I will be able to fix on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the clutch before anything else, when you first turn the car on, move the clutch in and out slowly and listen closely to see if you hear any odd noises in any certain area of the clutch pedal travel. It sounds like the clutch isn’t fully disengaging when you push it, and you are feeling the synchros in the transmission clash as a result. Does the clutch feel spongy? A car this year likely has a hydraulic clutch, and a master or slave cylinder going bad could suck in air and cause the clutch not to fully release.

Comment: There is an audible click as the clutch is close to being completely pushed. Thanks for the help!